# How to convert 'if' condition in NAnt into MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild

I have a NAnt script like below:

```
<if test="${a}>${b}">      
  <call target="target"/>
</if>
```

What I want is to convert it into MSBuild script. 
I found that there is  tag to write conditions but it is only used for defining property/item.

Can we write 'if' condition in MSBuild?
Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every msbuild task have an optional Condition parameter so you could do this:

```
<CallTarget Targets="target" Condition="${a} &gt; ${b}"/>
```

**Edit:** If you need a condition to execute multiple task, you could repeat the Condition parameter foreach task or you could encapsulate the multiple task call in a target

```
<Target Name="MultipleCall" Condition="${a} &gt; ${b}">
  <CallTarget Targets="targetA"/>
  <CallTarget Targets="targetB"/>
</Target>
```

(*The characters <  and > must be escaped*)

Comment: Thanks madgnome!
But what if we need a condition to execute multiple tasks:
<if test="${a}>${b}">      
  <call target="target1"/>
  <call target="target1"/>
  ...
  <call target="targetN"/>
</if>

Hope to hear from you.

Comment: Or not -- Choose/When seems appropriate, but unfortunately the Choose construct can't be used in a target. :-p